# Why is my question on hold?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928497/why-does-windows-not-show-up-in-grub-menu) a few days ago, and it is still on hold.

However, I have provided my boot-info summary, which I hope is enough information.

Furthermore, seeing that no one has answered yet, I am a little worried, because I do want to go back to my Windows 7 ASAP.

Just wondering why my question has not yet been answered and is still on hold.

Comment: It isn't on hold any more but note it was closed *twice* by reviewers - sounds to me like it may have been very unclear at that point.